# How to display controls contained within a separate class on a form?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a situation where I'm building a dynamic form, and clicking a button needs to generate several new controls. However, it's important that each set of controls only sees controls within that set, and not others. So, I've attempted to make a separate class to hold the controls in, and am wanting each click to create a new instance of this class.

My problem is how to make them display on the form?

Here is the class that holds the controls:

```
public class CrmCustomerSearchRow 
{
    public SimpleButton Remove = new SimpleButton();
    public LookUpEdit AttributeList = new LookUpEdit();
    public LookUpEdit ConditionalList = new LookUpEdit();
    public LookUpEdit EnumerableOptions = new LookUpEdit();
    public TextEdit NumericEntry = new TextEdit();
    private readonly StyleController _style = new StyleController();
    private CustomerSearchController _controller = new CustomerSearchController();

    public CrmCustomerSearchRow(int rowX, int rowY, CustomerSearchController control) : this(rowX, rowY, control, false){}

    public CrmCustomerSearchRow(int rowX, int rowY, CustomerSearchController control, bool firstGo)
    {
        //Initializers
        _controller = control;
        Remove = new SimpleButton()
            {
                Enabled = !firstGo,
                Image = Properties.Resources._001_02,
                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(rowX, rowY),
                Name = "simpleButtonRemove",
                Size = new System.Drawing.Size(34, 30),
                StyleController = _style
            };
        AttributeList = new LookUpEdit()
            {
                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Remove.Location.X + Remove.Width + 4, rowY),
                Name = "lookUpEditAttributeList",
                Size = new System.Drawing.Size(102, 20),
                StyleController = _style
            };
        AttributeList.Properties.Buttons.AddRange(new[]
            {
                new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton(
                                                      DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Combo)
            });
        ConditionalList = new LookUpEdit()
            {

                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(AttributeList.Location.X + AttributeList.Width + 4, rowY),
                Name = "lookUpEditConditionalList",
                Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 20),
                StyleController = _style
            };
        ConditionalList.Properties.Buttons.AddRange(new[]
            {
                new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton(
                                                        DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Combo)
            });
        EnumerableOptions = new LookUpEdit()
            {
                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(ConditionalList.Location.X + ConditionalList.Width + 4, rowY),
                Enabled = false,
                Name = "lookUpEditEnumerableOptions",
                Size = new System.Drawing.Size(91, 20)
            };
        ConditionalList.Properties.Buttons.AddRange(new[]
            {
                new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton(
                                                        DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Combo)
            });
        //Datastuffs
        AttributeList.Properties.DataSource = _controller.PropertyTypes;
        AttributeList.Properties.ValueMember = "AttributeTypeGuid";
        AttributeList.Properties.DisplayMember = "AttributeTypeName";
        //Event Handlers
        Remove.Click += Remove_Click;
        AttributeList.EditValueChanged += AttributeList_EditValueChanged;
        //Default Visibility and Enabledness
        ConditionalList.Enabled = false;
        EnumerableOptions.Visible = false;
        NumericEntry.Visible = false;
    }
```

And here is the attempt to add them to the form:

```
        private void simpleButtonAddTemplate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var oldX = int.Parse(simpleButtonAddTemplate.Location.X.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        var oldY = int.Parse(simpleButtonAddTemplate.Location.Y.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        var newX = oldX + int.Parse(simpleButtonAddTemplate.Size.Height.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) + 4;
        var newY = oldY;
        Rows.Add(
            new CrmCustomerSearchRow(oldX, oldY, _controller));
        simpleButtonAddTemplate.Location = new Point(newX, newY);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a `UserControl`.  It's a way of defining a user defined control that is made up of a number of other controls and that has it's own composite functionality.  Have your custom class extend `UserControl` rather than just being a stand alone class.  (You also probably want to create a UserControl through VS, as it will help you along rather than having you do everything manually.)

Once you've done that you can just create an instance of the user control and add it to the form; being a control itself this will be entirely valid.